# if else condition in MongoDB while aggregating

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I have a collection look like this:
[interference table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfiBf.png)

Here I want to search by either AP Name or BSSID, or both (BSSID is in prior).

Here is my code to query AP Name:

```
db.Int_Localization.aggregate([
{"$sort":{"ts":-1}},
{"$match": { "essid":"$int","floor":"$Floor","ts":{ "$gte" : "$from", "$lt":"$to"}}}, 
{"$project": {"_id":0, "AP Name":"$essid","Floor":"$floor","x location 1":"$xloc","y location 1":"$yloc","ts":"$ts"}}
            ])
```

Similarly, here is to query BSSID:

```
db.Int_Localization.aggregate([
{"$sort":{"ts":-1}},
{"$match": { "bssid":"$int2","floor":"$Floor","ts":{ "$gte" : "$from", "$lt":"$to"}}}, 
{"$project": {"_id":0, "AP Name":"$essid","Floor":"$floor","x location 1":"$xloc","y location 1":"$yloc","ts":"$ts"}}
            ])
```

So I want to combine these two codes and make an if condition, in which:

- If I type an AP Name to $int, it will show all documents with this AP Name
- If I type a BSSID to $int2, it will show all documents with this BSSID
- If I type both AP Name and BSSID to $int and $int2, it will show the exact AP Name and BSSID
- If I leave $int and $int2 blank, it will show all the documents

Is there any possible solution for this case? Thanks in advance

I tried to develop an application, which queries data from MongoDB server.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a dynamic query in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512584/how-to-create-a-dynamic-query-in-mongodb)